# Deleting inline item fails due to None id

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a quote model that has quoteitems as a related field.

```
class BusinessQuote(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(BusinessClient, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    site = models.ForeignKey(BusinessSite, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

and

```
class BusinessQuoteitem(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    quote = models.ForeignKey(BusinessQuote, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(BusinessJobtask, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ordered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

They are displayed in admin as inlines

```
class InlineQuoteItems(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BusinessQuoteitem
    extra = 0
    formfield_overrides = { ... }

class QuoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'date', 'client', 'site', 'tradename', 'total',     'converted']
    list_filter = ['tradename', 'client', ]
    inlines = [InlineQuoteItems]

admin.site.register(BusinessQuote,QuoteAdmin)
```

when I try and delete an inline item I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
Exception Location: /home/.../business/models.py in __str__, line 237
```

Line 237 relates to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%d" % (self.id)
```

Whats confusing is that this has normally worked out the box so I'm at a loss as to what could cause the inline delete to fail.

I am doing some javascript on the fields prior to submitting which totals the inline items and updates the invoice total but it doesn't touch id fields and as its client-side I cannot see it being an influence.

Comment: Try this `return self.id`

Comment: @ShafikurRahman sadly that gives __str__ returned non-string (type int) earlier i.e I cannot view a quote at all.

Comment: @ShafikurRahman but....  str(self.id) works?    Why is this?   It suggests that if you did something like return "Quote %d" % (self.id) or return "%s (#%d)" % (self.name, self.id) you would be back to my original problem?

Comment: Ops. It should. My mistake. The `__str__` magic method always expect string value.

Comment: The problem is in the use of the `%d` formatter itself, which as the error states only works with a number. You can use `%s` instead, or use the newer `.format()` method, or f-strings, or as you say just use `str()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - you were right!   I would have put money on you being wrong!  but you were right!   I'm sure using %d was ok in 1.9